# automated "secure" code signing

Tags: code-signing, jar-signing

I want to set up the jobs in our buildserver (Jenkins) to automatically sign the generated jars.

For obvious reasons I do not want to put the certificate and credentials in the version control, or even readable in the job configuration.

Ideally I want to have some kind of "signing server" where the buildserver can send a jar to, to be signed.

According to the documentation the Eclipse project has a [system like that](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JAR_Signing#Where_is_signing_done.3F). But there's no mention on the technology they use.

So does anybody know of a "singing server" solution, or a different way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about existing solution. However, I think you can build a solution on your own within a day:

Machine A will run Jenkins and have a shared folder
Machine B will run any application/web server (as example Apache + PHP) and which has signing keys.

As part of Jenkins job you do following actions:
a) Copy jars to shared folder
b) Run shell script "wget http:// machineBURL /sign.php?filename=SomeJar.jar"

On Machine B you will have PHP script, which will get a passed filename, get the jar with this filename from shared folder, sign it and put it back in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Eclispe WIKI documented the [sign process](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng-signedbuild),
for short

- Use scp to copy the eclipse-master-${buildId}.zip to the eclipse.org signing staging area using pserver.

`<exec dir="${packtmp}" executable="scp" output="signing.txt">
    <arg line="${archiveName} dev.eclipse.org:${stagingDirectory}"/>
    </exec>`

- Invoke the signing script /usr/bin/sign on signing server.

`<exec dir="." executable="ssh" output="signing.txt" append="true">
            <arg line="build.eclipse.org "cd ${stagingDirectory}; /usr/bin/sign ${stagingDirectory}/${archiveName} mail ${stagingDirectoryOutput}""/>
        </exec>`

- Poll the server for the signed file in the output directory.

`<exec dir="." executable="scp" output="signing.txt" append="true">
        <arg line="dev.eclipse.org:${stagingDirectory}/${buildId}-out/${archiveName} ${buildDirectory}/${buildLabel}"/>
        </exec>`